# Problems with passing of data from NSDictionary to NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to access a webservice using the json framework.

Code:

```
NSDictionary *allData;
NSMutableDictionary *displayData;
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://localhost/Gangbucks.svc/GetDealList"]; 
NSURL *jsonURL = [NSURL URLWithString:string];  
NSString *jsonData = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:jsonURL];  
self.allData = [jsonData JSONValue];  
NSLog(@"allData  value is1:%@", self.allData);      
self.displayData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:self.allData];
NSLog(@"displayData  value is2:%@", self.displayData);
```

`allData` works fine but I got an error on the `displayData`

```
2011-12-13 14:59:23.875 IPhone[352:207] -[__NSArrayM getObjects:andKeys:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x59e1c20
2011-12-13 14:59:23.878 IPhone[352:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM getObjects:andKeys:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x59e1c20'
*** Call stack at first throw:
```

Is it possible to pass data from  NSDictionary to NSMutableDictionary ?

Comment: Why do you need to declare the variables allData and displayData again if both of them are accessible through self?

Answer (score 3):

allData is apparently an NSArray, not an NSDictionary. You should go back and look at your JSON. The top-level there is probably an array.

Comment: I think allData is an NSDictionary here is the output

Comment: Where is the output? The runtime seems quite convinced it is an NSArray.

Comment: 2011-12-13 14:59:23.844 IPhone[352:207] allData  value is1:(
        {
        BusinessId = 6;
        BusinessName = "Beaver Dam Cleaners";
        CreationDate = "/Date(1317193287000+0800)/";
        DiscountDescription = "<null>";
        DiscountId = 3;
        DiscountPercentage = 10;
        DiscountTitle = "<null>";
        DiscountType = Baseline;
        ImagePath = "<null>";
        Rating = 5;
        ZipCode = 21030;
    }}

Comment: That's an array. Note it starts with a "(". You can also put a breakpoint there and ask the debugger: 'po [allData class]'

Comment: Thanks user1095223 and Firoze Lafeer. Firoze your right it's an NSArray. It's already working now, Here is my updated code


 NSArray *allData;
 NSMutableArray *displayData;

 
 self.allData = [jsonData JSONValue];  
 NSLog(@"displayData  value is1:%@", self.allData);  
 self.displayData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.allData];
 NSLog(@"displayData  value is2:%@", self.displayData);